# codificación UTF8 para que acepte tildaciones y ñ

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Estoy trabajando en un botón el cual me suba el archivo a una carpeta y al subirlo se me guarde la ruta en la base de datos para acceder al documento y al mismo tiempo estoy hago un link para que un usuario pueda bajar dicho documento ... el problema que me sucede es que cuándo un usuario sube un documento con una vocal con tilde o ñ el nombre del archivo sale con caracteres especiales en la base de datos este es el código :

`<label for="archivo" class="boton-subir icon-image"></label>
            <input class="botton" type="file" name="archivo" id="archivo" style="display: none">`

`$destino = '../subidos/';`

`$tmp = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
        $img = empty($_FILES['archivo']['name'])?"vacio":$destino. $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp, $img);
 $img='<a class="icon-download3" href="../subidos/'.$nombre.'"download>Descargar</a>';`

```
    `post::agregar($_SESSION['CodUsua'], $contenido, $img, $categoria);`
```

`class post{`

```
static function agregar($CodUsua, $contenido, $img,$categoria)
{
    $con = conexion("root", "");
    $consulta = $con->prepare("insert into post(CodPost, CodUsua, contenido, img,categoria) values(null, :CodUsua, :contenido, :img, :categoria)");
    $consulta->execute(array(':CodUsua' => $CodUsua,
                             ':contenido' => $contenido,
                             ':img' => $img,
                             ':categoria' => $categoria
        ));
}`
```

Comment: ¿Ha solucionado el problema?

Comment: no ... es que el problema se me da cuando inserto los datos en la base de datos

Answer (score 0):

Para ISO-8859-1:

`<html>
<head>
<title>Minha pagina</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">`

Para UTF-8:

`<html>
<head>
<title>Minha pagina</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

HTML5

`<meta charset="iso-8859-1" >`

o

`<meta charset="UTF-8" >`

Nota sobre la forma de guardar el archivo: Incluso si especifica uno de los encabezados arriba o con el charset que desea, el archivo debe guardarse en la codificación equivalente al charset especificado. Por ejemplo, si utiliza , el archivo debe guardarse en la codificación "ISO-8859-1, o Latin1 O ISO europeo ISO (o incluso ANSI si utiliza el Bloc de notas de Windows) ", pero si el charset es UTF-8, la codificación debe ser Unicode / UTF-8 también. Recordando que esta opción está disponible en el editor de texto utilizado para editar el archivo (notepad, notepad ++, gedit, textmate, textpad, vi, vim y varios otros).